# Why is make complaining "Nothing to be done for 'clean' "?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want `make` to remove all files except the source files and the make rule file (i.e. the file named `makefile`), so I added a phony rule at the end of my `makefile`:

```
.PHONY:clean

clean:
    $(shell ls | grep -v "[.][ch]" | grep -v makefile | xargs rm)
```

This does what I intend. But `make` always complains

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'clean'.
```

After I run `make clean`. Why does this message appear? And how can I make it disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `$(shell ...)` is unnecessary. It runs the command, then the output is used as if it was part of the Makefile. There is no output, so the resulting rule is:

```
clean:
```

i.e. the actual list of commands to update the clean target is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I removed the `$(shell )` and it worked.